# Weird tab character in VIM

Tags: vim, terminal

I am having issue figuring out what this weird white block of characters are. Anyone know how I can get rid of it? Thanks!

http://s11.postimg.org/kas9430gz/vimtab.png

**UPDATE:** Thanks to romanil's comment. It is Indent Guides.

Comment: put cursor on strangeness and do `ga`

Comment: Nice. :) Learned something today.

Comment: Hey @FredrikPihl. Sorry, what do you mean by do 'ga'? Thanks!

Comment: It looks like [indent guides](https://github.com/nathanaelkane/vim-indent-guides).

Comment: @HaiNguyen -- sorry for late reply. I mean, goto cmd-mode, i.e. hit ESC, then navigate so that the cursor sits on top of the strange character, then hit `ga` which is a vim command to Print the ascii value of the character under the cursor in decimal, hexadecimal and octal. See http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/various.html

Comment: @FredrikPihl That was exactly what I needed. The one I was wrestling with ended up being <^I> when I used the 'ga'. I was then able to do a simple %s/^I/  /g   To get the ^I in there I just did ctrl-v-I. thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Hex_dump

If you run the vi command

```
:%!xxd
```

It should convert the buffer into a hexdump and you should be able to see exactly what characters they correspond to.

Comment: This is the hexdump of those weird characters only. http://s11.postimg.org/f45o086qr/hexdump.png

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell from the image, but maybe there isn't a special character at all.  Vim highlights characters in certain conditions—e.g., search results or matching braces—which may look like this depending on your configuration.  You could turn off syntax highlighting using

```
:syntax off
```

or view the file in another program (e.g., `less`) to see if that's causing the issue.  If that doesn't help, you can always clean your file of any fancy characters using

```
:%s,[^\t -~],,g
```

Note that this will remove any accented characters as well.

Comment: I opened the file in sublime text, and saw nothing. Just empty spaces where the weirdness is showing in the image. Tried syntax off too.